# C# parse IEnumerable and string data in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have some code that passes an `IEnumerable` list and string data to the view.

How can I pass both an `IEnumerable` and a `string` together?

I have a Controller

```
private readonly IBooksBusinessLogic _books;

public ActionResult Books(int Id)
{
    IEnumerable<BooksViewModel> listData = _books.GetListByIdProvinsi(Id);

    String a = "estc";

    return View(listData);
}
```

but in view just show result list

```
@model IEnumerable<Library.ViewModel.BooksViewModel>

Name Library : (String from Controller)

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BooksName)
}
```

How can I pass the list and string together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have a string value you want to show in your view, put it in the `ViewBag`:

Action:

```
public ActionResult Books(int Id)
{
    IEnumerable<BooksViewModel> listData = _books.GetListByIdProvinsi(Id);

    ViewBag.Library = "estc";

    return View(listData);
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Library.ViewModel.BooksViewModel>

Name Library : @ViewBag.Library

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BooksName)
}
```

The other option is to create a View Model to hold both the library and the books, but that could be overkill. If you find yourself using a lot of views or actions that need to show both a library name and a list of books, I'd recommend looking into using a View Model.

Comment: @ViewBag.Library in the view

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exacly you are looking for.But, the `a`  variable only exists in your `Controller`, if you want to access it's value from `View`, use [`ViewBag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) or [`ViewData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.viewdata%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

Instead of:

```
String a = "estc";
```

Use:

```
ViewBag.A = "estc";
```

Then you can access your variable from your `View` using `ViewBag.A`